# How do I deploy MS hotfix KB959628 exe/msp via a gpo easily?

Tags: windows, group-policy, deployment

I have been given a Microsoft hotfix that I need to deploy over the entire domain.  I want to use GPO as the users do not have admin rights and Office was not deployed from an administrative point. It was deployed randomly on an individual basis.
  I tried converting the exe into an msi but when I ran the msi it just extracted the MSP file.

Is there an easy was I can deploy the MSP or EXE across various version of Office 2003 via a GPO?

I took a copy of Pro11.msi and tried running MSIexec.exe /a "[outlook.msi path]" /P "[Outlook.exe path]"
and the same with the MSP file.  Both times I got an error saying "The installation package could not be opened.  Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer Package".

Another solution maybe if it is possible to deploy via WSUS?

Comment: What solution are you using today to deploy patches/updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, actually.  If you don't have WSUS/SCCM/etc solution you use to push out patches, the easiest solution is a GPO with a startup script.

For example, what I've done below for a different hotfix.  (This is my batch file)

> echo off
>
> reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\HotFix\KB968730"
>   if %errorlevel%==1 (goto Install) else (goto End)
>
> REM If errorlevel returns a value of 1, it means the key is not present, thus the hotfix is not installed.  So install it.
>
> :Install
>
> `\\[Sysvol on my domain]\scripts\Scriptfiles\WindowsXP-KB968730-x86-ENU.exe /quiet`
>
> REM If errorlevel returns a value other than 1, the key is present, and the hotfix is already installed, or something odd's going on.  No installation.
>
> :End

Then I put that batchfile script up in `SYSVOL` where all domain computers and users can get at, and created a GPO to run that at startup.  [Startup scripts start in `SYSTEM` context, so user rights don't matter.]  Linked the GPO appropriately, wait, and the job's done next time the users reboot.

Startup scripts are configured under `Computer -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Scripts -> Startup`, through Group Policy Management Editor, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the post.  That is very similar to a script I wrote yesterday, but i didn't think I would be able to apply to users without admin rights

Comment: @user129472: startup scripts always run with admin rights.