# Best way to push out a hotfix

Tags: windows, update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deploy MS hotfix KB959628 exe/msp via a gpo easily?](https://serverfault.com/questions/410652/how-do-i-deploy-ms-hotfix-kb959628-exe-msp-via-a-gpo-easily)

We have a hotfix that we need to put onto our windows xp machines to get Single Sign on for web apps working. I cant add the hotfix to WSUS as it wont appear in the update catalogue.

What is the best way of pushing this out, we have no other 3rd party installers, am i going to have to create a GPO software policy to do it?

**EDIT** - the file is WindowsXP-KB953760-v2-x86-ENU.exe

Cheers
Luke

Comment: What extension is this hotfix? MSI? MSU? EXE? Please provide as much info as possible. If it's MSU you won't be able to install via group policy until you repackage as an MSI. You could also write a small script. More info needed to assist you though :)

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I may merge these two questions later and genericize the answers a bit -- they're two different ways to approach the same problem (deploying a .EXE hotfix via Group Policy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so firstly you will have to extract the contents of this hotfix, open CMD, locate your hotfix, and type the following:

```
WindowsXP-KB953760-v2-x86-ENU.exe /t:C:\<target_dir>\ /c
```

This will have extracted several files, including an MSP file.

You could then build a script based around this MSP file, create a script called "KB953760.bat", then host the file on your domain controller "DC1" in a share called "Patches" (replace these details with something more fitting to your network). The contents of the .bat file should be something along the lines of:

```
%windir%\system32\msiexec.exe /p \\DC1\patches\KB953760-v2-x86-ENU.msp /qn
```

The only issue with this script is that it will attempt to run it every time, you need some way for it to check if it is installed prior to grabbing the patch. I will see if I can refine it a bit but this should get you started at least.

Now you have your script you can make a GPO and include this script in the computer configuration section.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look at it. I kind of did'nt want to use a script cos it can get a bit messy, but i can see any other way of doing it at this point

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately the only really slick way to do it would be to implement WSUS on one of your servers, but if this is the only time you'll ever need to do something like this then WSUS is probably a bit overkill.

Comment: We're running wsus, but i cant get the hotfix to import, apparently MS dont allow you to import hotfixes into it for some odd reason?

Comment: What version of WSUS are you running? From version 3 and up it's possible.

Comment: We're running 3.2, i've tried looking for it using the Import updates function (i have used this successfully in the past) but this particular hotfix comes up with no results on a search. Is there another way to import it?